# Why there is not loadData() method in FileSystem?

Tags: 8, files

To use the `private://` scheme of Drupal 8 I had to :

- Create a folder outside the docroot folder
- Implement a  `$settings['file_private_path'] = '../private-files';` to designate this folder
- Make sure authorization matches the website user to write into it

Then I load the filesystem helper (I could use injection dependency but that is not the point here) :

```
$this->filesystem = \Drupal::service('file_system');
```

Prepare the directory in case it does not exists :

```
$this->filesystem->prepareDirectory('private://any_folder', FileSystemInterface::CREATE_DIRECTORY);
```

And then I could save a (unmanaged) file:

```
$this->filesystem->saveData(json_encode(['My Beautiful File Body']), 'private://any_folder/any_file.json', FileSystemInterface::EXISTS_REPLACE);
```

And this works fine.

But to load the file, I would have expected to have an "opposite" (say, `loadData()` ) method in `$this->filesystem`.

And as the file is unmanaged (which is fine) I cannout use `File Entity::load()` to load it.

So I end up with :

```
$loadedFile = json_decode(file_get_contents('private://any_folder/any_file.json'), JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY);
```

Which works fine, but raises questions :

- Is this a legitimate way to do it (meaning, using a Drupal helper to save a file, then loading it from a straight PHP function) ?
- Why there is no `loadData()` method in the `FileSystem` service as I would have expected ?
- How does the Drupal scheme 'public:// or private://) is resolved from this PHP function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions in respective order:

- Sure. If there's no built-in API function to make it easier, there's nothing wrong with using `file_get_contents` since the function can use Drupal's file stream protocols.
  The core test,
  [`FileSaveDataTest::testFileSaveData()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21tests%21Drupal%21KernelTests%21Core%21File%21FileSaveDataTest.php/function/FileSaveDataTest%3A%3AtestFileSaveData/9.0.x), is doing this to confirm that `saveData()` works.
- One can only guess about the requirements as the class was composed. [`saveData()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21File%21FileSystem.php/function/FileSystem%3A%3AsaveData/9.0.x) is a wrapper around a `file_put_contents()` op so that logging can take place when Drupal writes to a temp file. Perhaps there was no need to wrap `file_get_contents` in the same way?
- Drupal has a [`StreamWrapperManager`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21StreamWrapper%21StreamWrapperManager.php/class/StreamWrapperManager/9.0.x) service class that registered different custom `myscheme://` streams with PHP. This manager makes use of core PHP function [`stream_wrapper_register()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-wrapper-register.php) to register any injected class that has the tags: `{ name: stream_wrapper, scheme: myscheme }`. For example, look at [`CoreServiceProvider::register()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21CoreServiceProvider.php/function/CoreServiceProvider%3A%3Aregister/9.0.x) which registers the `private://` scheme when it detects `file_private_path` settings has been set.